# Converting values from array to different values and making a new string

Tags: vb.net

I have a string which I have split into array.
This is the string I'm sending. The string is actually numbers, it varies and it goes from 1 to 565.

```
 magboxcreator(DirectCast(MychannelsListView.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("FIELD23"))
```

I have a function which splits that string into array:

```
Public Function magboxcreator(channelnr As String)
    Dim chars As Char() = channelnr.ToCharArray()

End Function
```

Now that i have numbers in array, which are now strings/chars, i want to make a function which will "convert" those "numbers" to respective values and make a string which i will send to another function.

For every value i have a consistent counter-value (the value i need every char from array to be converted).

Example of what i'm trying to achieve:

If i parse value `72` i will get 2 values in array `7` and `2`.

Value `7` needs to be converted to string: `-kqt 0x37`

Value `2` needs to be converted to string: `-kqt 0x32`

In some other case if i get another value, let's say '3', that value needs to be converted to string `-kqt 0x32`

My end result (final string i want to send to another function) needs to be `-kqt 0x37 && -kqt 0x32`

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle this using a lookup table.

```
Private mLookup As New Dictionary(Of Char, String)

Public Sub New()
    mLookup("7"c) = "-kqt 0x37"
    .... add more values
End Sub

Public Function Convert(value As String) As String
    Dim chars As Char() = value.ToCharArray()

    Dim output As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each c In chars
        output.Append(mLookup(c)).Append(" && ")
    Next
    Return output.ToString().TrimEnd("&"c, " "c)

End Function
```